# Handling AfterRowActivate and CellChange events simultaneously

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm using a UltraGrid and I have interest in handling AfterRowActivate and CellChange events. Clicking on a cell in a boolean type column and a non-active row triggers both events, first AfterRowActivate and then CellChange. Is there any way of knowing in the method that handles the AfterRowActivate that event was fired by clicking on a cell in the boolean column and therefore also will be fired CellChange event?

Comment: There is an AfterCellActivate that is raised before the CellChanged event and that contains the information about the cell clicked. AfterRowActivate receives a normal EventArgs parameter without any information about the current cell. Why do you need to handle AfterRowActivate?

Comment: The point is that I have a UltraPanel within a UltraDockManager and want to show or hide the panel depending on whether the active row has checked a boolean column. So I need the AfterRowActivate to show or hide the panel, but also need the CellChange for the same purpose. AfterCellActivate is raised before CellChange but after AfterRowActivate, therefore in method that handles the AfterRowActivate I don't know whether the value of the boolean cell will change or not as result of that only action(clicking the cell of the boolean column in a non-active row).Any idea will be very helpful. @Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to find if a boolean cell was clicked in AfterRowActivate event. This event may fire and when the row was activated after clicking on row selector for example. What you can try is get the UIElement where the user clicked. If the UIElement is CheckEditorCheckBoxUIElement this most probably shows that check box cell was clicked.

```
private void UltraGrid1_AfterRowActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as UltraGrid;
    if(grid == null)
        return;

    //  Get the element where user clicked
    var element = grid.DisplayLayout.UIElement.ElementFromPoint(grid.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));

    //  Check if the element is CheckIndicatorUIElement. If so the user clicked exactly
    //  on the check box. The element's parent should be CheckEditorCheckBoxUIElement
    CheckEditorCheckBoxUIElement checkEditorCheckBoxElement = null;
    if(element is CheckIndicatorUIElement)
    {
        checkEditorCheckBoxElement = element.Parent as CheckEditorCheckBoxUIElement;
    }
    //  Check if the element is CheckEditorCheckBoxUIElement. If so the user clicked
    //  on a check box cell, but not on the check box
    else if(element is CheckEditorCheckBoxUIElement)
    {
        checkEditorCheckBoxElement = element as CheckEditorCheckBoxUIElement;
    }

    //  If checkEditorCheckBoxElement is not null check box cell was clicked
    if(checkEditorCheckBoxElement != null)
    {
        //  You can get the cell from the parent of the parent of CheckEditorCheckBoxUIElement
        //  Here is the hierarchy:
        //  CellUIElement
        //      EmbeddableCheckUIElement
        //          CheckEditorCheckBoxUIElement
        //              CheckIndicatorUIElement
        //  Find the CellUIElement and get the Cell of it

        if(checkEditorCheckBoxElement.Parent != null && checkEditorCheckBoxElement.Parent.Parent != null)
        {
            var cellElement = checkEditorCheckBoxElement.Parent.Parent as CellUIElement;
            if(cellElement != null)
            {
                var cell = cellElement.Cell;
            }
        }
    }
}
```